# How can I split RootQuery?

Tags: graphql

my question is simple: how can I split the code ?
or refactorise it, because if I have 30 queries its impossible to read ...
I'd like to create one file for every query, but i can't do it.
any idea ?

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    book: {
      type: BookType,
      args: {
        id: {
          type: GraphQLID
        }
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return _.find(books, { id: args.id })
      }
    },
    author: {
      type: AuthorType,
      args : {
        id: {
          type: GraphQLID
        }
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return _.find(authors, { id: args.id })
      }
    },
    authors: {
      type: new GraphQLList(AuthorType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return authors
      }
    },
    books: {
      type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return books
      }
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With variables?

```
const book = {
  type: BookType,
  args: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLID
    }
  },
  resolve(parent, args) {
    return _.find(books, { id: args.id })
  }
}

const author = {
  // ...
}

const authors = {
  // ...
}

const books = {
  // ...
}

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: { book, author, authors, books }
})
```